# PHP Curl File Upload Multipart Boundary

Tags: php, file, curl, upload, boundary

Writing an application that proxies a file upload. I'm using CURL to post the file but having a few problems. Posting to the script is ok, its posting from the script to the next server which is the problem. I keep getting this error from the server:

"the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

here is my code:

```
            $post = $_POST;

            // allow for file upload proxying
            if( !empty( $_FILES ) ){
                    // add to post data
                    foreach( $_FILES as $name => $upload ){
                            $post[ $name ] = '@' . $upload[ 'tmp_name' ] . ';type=image/png';
                    }   
            } 

            // init curl
            $ch = curl_init( $url );

            // configure options
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );

            // post data
            if( !empty( $post ) ){
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
                    // for file uploads, multi-part
                    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Content-type: multipart/form-data;'
                    ) );
            }   

            // execute and get return value 
            $return = trim( curl_exec( $ch ) );

            // cleanup
            curl_close( $ch );
            unset( $ch );
```

Everything I've read online suggests that this should work and also that setting the header content type is unnecessary, but when I remove the content type I get this error:

"the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is null"

any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: have a look here: https://gist.github.com/maxivak/18fcac476a2f4ea02e5f80b303811d5f

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem was, but I was working locally when I posted this. Moved the code onto a live server and the problem disappeared...